# Responsive staggered rows in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, user-experience

I'm developping an interface like this :

http://codepen.io/clemeeent/pen/NPPEzE

```
  O O O O O O O 
 O O O O O O O O
  O O O O O O O
```

So in staggered rows. I tried to do this as basic bootstrap rows and simply center them. Their lenght being different it sorts of works...

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10 centered">
         <div class="day"></div>
         <div class="day"></div>
         <div class="day"></div>
         <div class="day"></div>
    </div
</div>
...
```

Problem is it looks like nothing when reducing window because of the rows... Should I try sort of js script which switch the .day in the next .row...? I can't figure out any solution to get a fluid grid of my staggered elements...

In mobile view it should looks like :

```
  O O
 O O O
  O O
 O O O
```

Any idea would be much appreciated !

Comment: How do you know where to split the rows?

Comment: That's the point, it always had to be staggered. So probably have to split the rows everytime there's no more space for the 8th element... Then it will be 7-6-7-6, then 6-5-6-5-6, then 5-4-5-4-5-4-5...etc

Comment: Just curious, is there a reason the numbers 9, 17 and 18 are missing?

Comment: So do you know the width of each item?

Comment: Yep, each item has a static width of 90px. @A.L : Just a mistake while doing the thing quickly on codepen :p

Comment: There may be a solution using [media queries](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries) to set different widths then set manually the margin of the `nth` element but it requires some work (calculate manually how many elements are displayed per row) and it won't be totally *fluid*.

Comment: I'll try to do the maths... Maybe it's the only solution. Still waiting a bit longer if someone has another idea. But thx all :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing I can think of (not involving a lot of javascript calculation) is to eliminate the rows and do a number of media queries using `nth-child`.

Essentially, give the starting member of every odd row a left margin and a clear left, and the start of every even row a clear left. The menu does not smoothly reflow, it will depend on how many breakpoints you're willing to put in.

Here's an example of three media queries reflowing from 400px to 900px [Codepen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oggJXo)

Example of what I did:

```
@media (max-width: 550px) {  
  .day:nth-child(5n + 1) { /*odd rows*/
    clear: left;
    margin-left: 60px; /*half the width of .day + existing margin*/
    background: red;
  }
  .day:nth-child(5n + 3) { /*even rows*/
    clear: left; 
  }
}
```

I gave the first of each odd row a background color to show what was happening. If you're willing to write more media queries, you could get a pretty smooth reflow, or just adjust the size of the containing div and center it.

Comment: Thank you mate for taking the time of explaining ! This works really well :). I really appreciate